# regex custom lenght but no whitespace allowed

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

i'm not practice in regExp and i was trying to have one that checks for a min and max length, and deny the user to set blank space in the input field.

Example

`('te')` return false

`('te ssss .  ')` return false

`('teeeeeeeessttt')` return true

I tried to wrote this but i'm not able to check the white space

```
export const lengthAndBlankspaceValidation = (inputValue: any, minLength: number, maxLength: number) => {
  if (inputValue === undefined || inputValue === null || inputValue.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  const regex = new RegExp(`^.{${minLength},${maxLength}}$|s+`);
  const isValid = regex.test(inputValue);

  return isValid;
};
```

how can i check for blank space in this case ?

Comment: Your regex pattern does not make sense. If min is 4 and max is 6, it looks like `S^.{4,6}$|s+`. What you want is probably `const regex = /^\S{4,6}$/`, i.e. ``new RegExp(`^\\S{${minLength},${maxLength}}$`)``

Comment: sorry i mistake the copy paste :) edited now.

Comment: i tried to insert ``` new RegExp(`^\\S{${minLength},${maxLength}}$`) ```, but when i set a blank space the regExp return me the result that i expect for a wrong input ( if there are blank space or not  max or min length, i need an error )

Comment: Then just use `\\s`, why `s+`? Why use a regex to check a string length?

Comment: There are so many answers about it that  I doubt it will add any value. Just use `/\s/.test(text)` to see if there is any whitespace in the string and use `if (text.length < minLength || text.length > maxLength) { ERROR }` to check the length.